# R - sum rows in data fame with string patterns that meet one of multiple criteria

Tags: r

I have data structured as shown below. I'd like to create two variables that count the number of variables containing strings that meet one of multiple conditions. For example, df$negative would be the rowsum of customer variables that contain the string patterns c("No", "Did Not") and df$positive would be the rowsum of customer variables containing at least one of the string patterns c("Rent", "Selected")

```
               Customer 3               Customer 4               Customer 5
1                    <NA>   Showed - Did not select                   No fit
2       Showed - Selected                      <NA>                    <NA>
3                    <NA>                    Rented                    <NA>
4                    <NA>                     <NA>                   No fit
```

so df$negative and df$positive for row 1 would be 2 and 0, respectively.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
rowSums(sapply(df, function(i) grepl(tolower('No|Did Not'), tolower(i))))
#[1] 2 0 0 1

#and similarly for positive

rowSums(sapply(df, function(i) grepl(tolower('Rent|Selected'), tolower(i))))
#[1] 0 1 1 0
```